# div should be refreshed every three seconds using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

below is my script in that, particular div should be refresh every three seconds. how to add the time interval in my code using jquery and ajax?

```
 <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {

               $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
                     var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
                       $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication',
                            data: form_data,
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                scrollDown();
                                var message = $("#messagee").val();

                                $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent active"><div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div></div>');

                                $('#messagee').val('');
                            },
                            error: function ()
                            {
                                alert('failed');
                            }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    scrollDown();
                    function scrollDown() {
                        $('.msg_container_base').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg_container_base').prop("scrollHeight")}, 200);
                    }
                });
 </script>
```

Comment: When should the interval start?

Comment: every three seconds particular div should be refresh,,,in chat application

Answer (score 2):

To refresh the div every 3Sec.
You can use "setInterval" function.
And to stop this interval you can use "clearInterval" function.
The simple code is as follows:

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
 // alert("Hello"); 
 //Your Div's ID    
}, 3000);
/* later */
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
```

This code simply calls the alert every 3seconds,so modify the above code and put the div's id to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 getMessage();
}, 3000);
```

`setIterval` lets you to repeat a function or a code block every n seconds.

I think you should add your ajax call into a function.

```
function getMessage () {
 //Your ajax call here 
}
```

This way the code could be reused more times without repeating it.

Comment: add your ajax call into a function and call that function in the `setInterval` function

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval javascript function for that. check the code snippet below

```
setInterval(scrollDown, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. Please check below code.

```js
function animatedText() {
    $('.text').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200, function() {
          $('.text').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200);
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        animatedText();
    },3000);
}
animatedText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text">Animated Text</div>
```

Comment: your code is working but taking so much time and i dnt need animated at all@Shyam

Comment: It will make a call after every 3 seconds, Animation I just added so you can verify that call duration for 3 seconds. You can replace that animation code with add your code.